# Java Regex not finding any matches

Tags: java, regex, match

I have the following example string:

`some random text term "thing I want" some more random text term "thing I want"`

And I'm using the following regular expression:

`term\s?\"?([^\n\r]*)\"?`

However my matcher can't find any matches whatsoever and I can't figure out why.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String regex = "term\\s?\\\"?([^\\n\\r]*)\\\"?";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            list.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `cannot find symbol:   variable string`. Make your samples easy to test (include imports, declare everything which is used), so that not 100 readers have to figure out, what is needed.

Comment: That does find a match for me - are you sure you're not getting one?  Are you possibly checking for it in `list` rather than `mesh`?

Comment: what are your exactly expect?

Comment: @userunknown I wrote the string above, you're right about the imports though. I've included the imports.

Comment: @ShenYudong I expect the matcher to find a match on _term "thing i want"_ and then add the _thing i want_ to the arraylist

Comment: @Stinna: A good improvement. Do you know jshell, an interactive shell for Java snippets, available in the beta of Java9? I figuered out, that string="some random..." but had to do the masking of the " myself, and so has any user, trying to reproduce your error, whether in jshell or in other tools to test code snippets. Make it easy for people, willing to help, to help.

Comment: @userunknown Okay, i will do so in the future thanks for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

That actually does match for me, but it returns this, which isn't quite what you want:

```
thing I want" some more random text term "thing I want"
```

This is happening because your regex allows the capturing group to include quotes, so there's no way to delineate the end of group and it consumes the rest of the string.  You can prevent this as follows (assuming the quotes are mandatory):

```
String regex = "term\\s?\\\"([^\\n\\r\"]*)\\\"";
```

Comment: You're a hero! Okay so this finds a match however it seems to only be finding one match rather than the multiple matches it should find. Should i put the matcher.find() in a for loop or is there some standard way to do this?

Comment: Yay!  Yes - just change "if" to "while" and you should be away!

Comment: Glad I could help!  If this has solved your problem, would you mind clicking the "tick" button?  This marks the question as solved, so other people know not to look into it.  (And gives me some extra points \o/ )